# Paginated + Ajax table in Django

Tags: html, django, datatable, middleware

I simply want to show off a model in a table that is paginated and sortable on the various fields. Bonus points if the pagination and sorting doesn't cause a page reload. Double bonus points if the pagination is done with infinite scrolling.

I'm sure everyone here has written and rewritten this functionality.

Is there a simple middleware/template/project/something that I can drop into my django project and it 'will-just-work'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like jQuery, [this post](http://bcurtu.com/?p=478) has a neat solution for Django+Ajax pagination (doesn't directly implement sorting though).

Comment: @Titusz, try the cached text-only version at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BhHhTd7NEFcJ:bcurtu.com/%3Fp%3D478+django+ajax+site:bcurtu.com&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1 (and it would be nice of you to email Bosco Curtu to let him know his server is down, in case he doesn't know).

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

On the datatables.net plugin site, a full demo example is available on the server side with a datatable feeded with JSON type data : http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/django

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: It look's like the page and the repository linked have been deleted. I would not recommend using my answer or the archived link: [https://web.archive.org/web/20110719030929/http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/django]as it is a decade old now and web technologies have nicely moved along. :-D

Answer (score 1):

GitHub seems sluggish at the moment, but you may also want to check out [django-sorting](http://github.com/ericflo/django-sorting/tree/master).